# How to enable SYN Cookies on Debian 7.5?

Tags: tcp

How do I enable SYN Cookies on Debian 7.5?

```
nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

`#net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1` remove here the #

```
sysctl -p

service network restart
```

Is that the correct way? Or what must I look at?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to restart the network service, only to change the kernel setting as you did in `/etc/sysctl.conf` followed by `sysctl -p` to reload its content.